# Slicing the Values of a Dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, if-statement, slice

I'm trying to write a function that takes three parameters: a dictionary, `emp_dict`, a string, `username`, and a number `emp_no`.

The key values in the dicionary store employee number as the key and a string for the employee name. The first three letters or the last three letters of the username must match the first three letters of the employee's name.

How can I compare the string `username` to each of the dictionary's first three value fields.

Other constraints include:

- The given employee number exists in the dictionary
- The username must be at least 4 characters
- The first three letters or the last three letters of the username must match the first three letters of the employee's name

Here is what I have so far:

```
def validate_employee(emp_dict, username, emp_no):
if emp_no not in emp_dict:
    return False
elif len(username) < 4:
    return False
```

This is where I'm having trouble. How can I write the next two elifs?

```
elif username[0:2}.lower == emp_dict.values():
    return True




emp_dict={1111:'Sim',1234:'James',9999:'Amy',5555:'Jessica'}
username='Jess' 
emp_no=5555
print(validate_employee(emp_dict, username, emp_no))
```

I apologize if I didn't ask this very well or if I made some pretty rookie mistakes. I'm pretty new to StackOverflow and Python programming in general. I sometimes have some trouble thinking through some problems logically.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0):

You only have to write one logic which is:

```
elif username[:3] in map(lambda x:x[:3],emp_dict.values()) or username[-3:] in map(lambda x:x[:3],emp_dict.values()):
    return True
```

Or if it is not Case sensitive:

```
elif username[:3].lower() in map(lambda x:x[:3].lower(),emp_dict.values()) or username[-3:].lower() in map(lambda x:x[:3].lower(),emp_dict.values()):
    return True
```

Example:

```
>>> emp_dict={1111:'Sim',1234:'James',9999:'Amy',5555:'Jessica'}
>>> username='Jess'
>>> username[:3] in map(lambda x:x[:3],emp_dict.values())
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simpler and laconic:

```
def validate_employee(emp_dict, username, emp_no):
    if emp_no not in emp_dict:
        return False
    if len(username) < 4:
        return False

    head = username[:3]
    if list(filter(lambda x: x[:3] == head or x[:3] == head, emp_dict.values())):
        return True
```

It's not necessary to write `elif` after statements with `return` (sometimes such statements also called *guards*).

Answer (score 0):

My attempt with builtin `any()` and `str.startswith()`:

```
employees = {}
employees[0] = 'smith john'
employees[1] = 'paolo smith'
employees[3] = 'jack daniels'


def validate(emp_dict, username, emp_no):
    if emp_no not in emp_dict:
        return False

    if len(username) < 4:
        return False

    if not any(e.startswith(username[:3]) or e.startswith(username[-3:]) for e in emp_dict.values()):
        return False

    return True

print(validate(employees, 'paolo john', 3))
print(validate(employees, 'john paolo', 3))
```

Prints:

```
True
False
```